# Excel VBA Delete Method To NOT Delete The Headline

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a loop which deletes all cells that has none of these two values: "OI" or "SI".

When I execute the macro, I get:

> Delete Method of range class failed

I figure it out and it is becaues it tries to delete the headline.

How can I avoid the deletion of the Headline?

```
Sub DeleteValues()   

Dim i As Integer
Dim MFG_wb As Workbook
Dim Dep As Integer

Set MFG_wb = Workbooks.Open _
("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate

Dep = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Range("O2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = Dep To 1 Step -1
    Cells(i, 15).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "SI" Or Selection.Value = "OI") Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to fix the Loop Condition.
From **1** to **2**

```
For i = Dep To 2 Step -1
    Cells(i, 15).Select
    If Not (Selection.Value = "SI" Or Selection.Value = "OI") Then
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

For Example: if **Dep** is **5**. The loop will decrement till **Dep** is **1**. After that, it will decrement to **0** and it will jump out off the Loop.
So you have to Set the **Loop Condition** to **2**, so it would Exit the Loop when he get's to the Header Row.

Answer (score 3):

just don't try to delete the top line.
instead of `For i = Dep To 1 Step -1`, use:

```
For i = Dep To 2 Step -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete row where there is a table header, you have to convert the table in a interval then delete it. Or just on error resume next:

```
Sub DeleteValues()


Dim i As Integer
Dim MFG_wb As Workbook
Dim Dep As Integer



Set MFG_wb = Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Users\rosipov\Desktop\eliran\MFG - GSS\MFG Daily\Fast Daily " & 
Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") & ".xlsx", _
UpdateLinks:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Activate

Dep = MFG_wb.Sheets("Aleris").Range("O2").End(xlDown).Row

On Error Resume Next
For i = Dep To 1 Step -1
    If Not (Cells(i, 15).Value = "SI" Or Cells(i, 15).Value = "OI") Then
        Cells(i, 15).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i    

End Sub
```